# Using degrees symbols in React and JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm coding out a temperature app with React and I'm on the part where I'm displaying the different temperatures within the element.

Now I'm trying to do `&deg;F` to return Fahrenheit, but then it occurred to me: this is `JSX`, not HTML. Sure enough, when you put this into a component, it returns an error because the DOM is trying to read JavaScript.

Is there a good workaround for this?

Comment: [html entities work in JSX](https://codesandbox.io/s/l42k80nl27). Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: try to use [unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2109/index.htm) in your jsx. `\u2109`
This [article](https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html) will help you solve the issue.

Comment: can you show what you tried? because html entities work in jsx.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I actually botched this question, I was attempting to put `&deg;` next to the props I passed when I called the component, not into the component itself. When I put the symbol into the component, it worked.

Comment: @logos_164 That's alright. There's a few ways to work around that [listed in the documentation](https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#html-entities).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use HTML entities within literal text in JSX.

```
function App() {
  return <h1>&deg;F</h1>;
}
```

You can use the unicode number corresponding to the entity if you need it inside a string.

```
function App() {
  return <h1>{'\u00b0'}</h1>;
}
```

A few other ways of approaching it are listed in the [JSX Gotchas part of the documentation](https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#html-entities).

Answer (score 2):

Usually I just type the actual symbol. In your case: `ºF`

Answer (score 2):

You can use "" symbols inside JSX and write the special code inside of it to render it.

ex:

```
return (<span>"&deg;"F</span>);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on a similar feature recently. Following all work for me:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>&deg;</h1>
        <h1>&#176;</h1>
        <h1>&#x00B0;</h1>
        <h1>&#xB0;</h1> {/* for hex code, you can omit the leading zeros */}
        <h1>{'\u00B0'}</h1>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Reference for the unicode of degree symbol:
https://graphemica.com/%C2%B0