# ReatJS - Unable to display degree sign fed in from string

Tags: css, reactjs, unicode, fonts

The app i am building reads in data from an external source such as..

```
It is currently
```

and

```
&#xb0;F outside.
```

The app then concatenates these variables along with the environmental data.  We then parse this string into a component where we display it.  It should look like..

```
It is currently °F outside.
```

however what is actually seen is

```
It is currently &#176;F outside.
```

I have tried using the various degree symbol codes defined [here](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/math/degree-sign/), however the app always displays the raw code instead of displaying the symbol.

The index.html meta also has `<meta charset="utf-8" />` and have tried removing the font assigned to the string to use the system font.  The text is displayed in a standard div.

This is just one example, but i need to be able to display strings that are built from external sources that could contain any unicode character.

Currently lost as to why the symbols are not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried this `&deg;F`?**

Working in normal HTML:

```html
<h1>&deg;F</h1>
```

**Or in actual React app:**

[image: Edit nice-curie-kbzwl]

Comment: I have.  It is literally rendering "<h1>&deg;F</h1>" to the screen.

Comment: How come? Could you share your code here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51135958/using-degrees-symbols-in-react-and-jsx